# Struts.xml define global result type as Tile

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, tiles2

I am using Tiles with Struts2. In struts.xml I need to define `<result-types>` for every package. How can I make it global so all packages show type as **tiles** like `<result type="tiles"></result>`

```
 <package name="student" namespace="/student" extends="struts-default">

        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult"/>
        </result-types>
</package>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd put your actions into a package extending `"tiles-default"` instead of `"struts-default"`. The `"tiles-default"` package already defines a `"tiles"` result type.

Alternatively, you could create a parent package that extends `"tiles-default"` and use that as your parent package for all your app's packages.

Comment: Or he could define a stack that extends anything, or a new one from scratch so long has he defines result-types with a result-type tag naming the tiles result, with a default attribute and a value of true (he has everything currently in his current xml except 'default ="true"')... as explained here: http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/result-configuration.html

Comment: @dave-newton, I have added your solution in the question at bottom. I hope that's what you wanted me to do. right?

Comment: @Rashid No, there already *is* a "tiles-default" package, provided by the tiles plugin. You're doing what Quaternion suggests, but naming it the same as a package provided already.